# Web page loading with JSON data as content in Springboot application hosted on ROSA

Tags: java, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8, aws-route53

I'm trying to configure springboot(ver 2.5.15) web application in DEV environment via ROSA.
Application is running fine in localhost and the CI and CD pipeline is successful but upon trying to access the DEV url, the web page is loading with this JSON content. Also, there's no error in logs.

`{ "_links" : { "profile" : { "href" : "application-dev-url/profile" } } }`

Front end is JSP and using embedded tomcat server

I'm not sure where the issue is, as **the application is running fine in localhost**.